# How to add a bottom bar for citations in QGIS Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2

I want to add something like the bottom bar in this picture in order to include my citations. [image: Look at the Bottom Blue Bar]

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would probably be to create the bottom bar as picture file (jpeg, png...) and add it to your layout as an image.

[image]

Click and drag to draw a box, and then in the *Main properties* on the right hand side browse for your image.

[image]

Adjust the box to size.

[image]

If you are looking for a good open source image editing software I would recommend GIMP (GNU Image Manipulation Program) https://www.gimp.org/